# How to handle the JAVA WatchService Overflow event?

Tags: java, java-8, nio, watchservice

I want to detect the *Creation* and *Modification* of files using JAVA. I am using the **WatchService** API provided by JDK 7.

So, when there is multiple file creation at a given instance there is a level that the watch service can handle and then it generates and **OVERFLOW** event.

*Sample code part is provided below.*

What is the most suitable way to handle that situation when there is and overflow event thrown in order to detect the creation of all the files?

```
for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
    WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
    // TBD - provide example of how OVERFLOW event is handled
    if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
         System.err.println("OVERFLOW !");
         continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully, you have already found a solution for this. Usually the idea is to process newly created files and move the processed files to a different directory.

There are two possible options to deal with this:

- Prevent OVERFLOW from occurring
- Handle OVERFLOW if it has still occurred

**Prevent OVERFLOW from occurring** 
The idea is to clear the Operating System buffer quickly and populating a queue with the event information and then having multiple threads process the events in the queue.

**Handle OVERFLOW if it has still occurred**

If the OVERFLOW still occurs,

- stop listening to events
- clear the queue
- call listFiles() on the directory
- start listening to events again
- insert the listed files in the queue

Comment: hey! Please could you provide simple examples implementing your suggestions? A link too shown these examples would be much appreciated as I'm dealing with the same issue but can't really find where any of your suggestions are done. Thanks!